# Finding the stationary point on the curve: $e^x+ye^{-x}=2e^2$

Tags: derivatives, self-learning, implicit-differentiation

So I'm trying to find the stationary point of this equation: $e^x+ye^{-x}=2e^2$. This is my attempt at doing so:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}(e^x+ye^{-x})=\dfrac{d}{dx}(2e^2)$$
$$e^x+(-ye^{-x}+\frac{dy}{dx}\times e^{-x})=0$$
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{-e^x+ye^{-x}}{e^{-x}}$$ Setting $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0$
$$-e^x+ye^{-x}=0$$
$$y=\dfrac{e^x}{e^{-x}}=e^{2x}$$

I can't seem to draw a conclusion, and I don't know how to proceed, could anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could solve for $y$ too (from the first equation).

Comment: @Maesumi I'm not sure I understand. Could you show the most efficient way to do this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you have two relations between abscissa and ordinate of stationary point .

$1.)$ The curve itself.

$2.)$ $y=e^{2x}$

Substitute $y=e^{2x}$ in the equation of the curve, you will get $x$-coordinate of stationary point and you know how to calc. $y$-coordinate then.

Answer (score 0):

First find $y$:
$$y = 2e^{2+x}-e^{2x}$$
So that:
$$y' = 2e^{2+x}-2e^{2x}=0$$
$$e^2=e^x \to x=2$$